# Conditional probablity for a given seqeunce

Tags: probability

I have 2 questions.

1. How can I calculate the probability of getting a specific sequence of heads vs tails?
2. If I have a given sequence of tosses, how can I use this information to help me guess the next flip?

Let's suppose that I have a fair, 2 sided coin.

My attempts for 1: Let's suppose I want to know what the probability of HTTH occurring is:
P(H) = .5
P(HT) = P(HT) / (P(HH) + P(HT) + P(TH) + P(TT)) = .25/(.25 + .25 + .25 + .25) = 0.25
P(HTT) = P(HTT) / (P(HHH) + ... + P(TTT)) = 0.125
P(HTTH) = .... = 0.0625

Is is also accurate to just say P(HTTH) = P(H)*P(T)*P(T)*P(H)?

My attempts for 2: Assume I have TTTT, what is the probability of having TTTTH? I feel like
having 4 tails in a row would increase the chances of getting a heads at the end. But if I use the above, P(TTTTH) = P(TTTTT) which does not seem right to me. Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for your help. I appreciate you!

Comment: With your coin The probability of getting H given the past is always 1/2, since the past doesn’t have any bearings on the future tosses due to independence.

Comment: @utobi, I agree with your statement. However, if I have HHHH, what is the probability that my next flip will be T? Does P(HHHHT) = P(HHHHT) ?

Comment: The ans. to the second question is yes, both are equal to .5^5